# route.solve() - RouteEdges does not give expected output

Tags: route

RouteEdges do gives multiple entries for single SourceOID when solving route through route.solve().
Reference URL - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/network-analyst/route.htm

**Actual Output:**

```
SourceOID || FromPosition || ToPosition
28760116 || 0 || 0.210675
28760116 || 0.210675 || 0.672682
28760116 || 0.672682 || 1
```

**Expected Output:**

```
SourceOID || FromPosition || ToPosition
28760116 || 0 || 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check below URl for Solution.

URL: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-network-analyst-questions/route-solve-routeedges-does-not-give-expected/m-p/1241686#M8145